# Socket.io fires connect event just after the second connect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io with the latest version of node.js and socket.io shows an curious behavior:
The connect event fires on client side but not on server side for the first time.
After a reload or simply loading the page again the event got fired on both - client and server - side correctly.
What's wrong (with my code?)?

```
// Client
var socket = io.connect(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname, {
    'sync disconnect on unload': true
});

socket.on('connect', function() {
    alert("Connect");
    // Do other stuff
});
```

-

```
// Server
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("connection");

    io.sockets.on('connect', function(socket) {
        console.log("connect");
     });
});
```

Started the server and loaded the page:
Client fires the alert, server just logs `connection`. Now loading the page again, it logs both `connection` and `connect`.

Update:
It seems that just the very first connection has such issues, afterwards it works everywhere as expected. Just after every node server (re)start, that behavior appears.
Note: node itself delivers the page where the socket.io is used and that works even on the first request, so a node issue should be excluded then.
Browser is also doesn't matter, it's the same on every browser.

Answer (score 0):

For Socket.IO, `connection` is the server-side equivalent of `connect` on the client side. Therefore, when you're inside the callback for the `connection` event, the socket has already established a connection and you don't need to listen on some other event. I'm not sure what `connect` on the server side is, but it is not documented and does not work.

```
// on the server
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // this connection has already been established
  // no other handler is required
});

// on the client
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('connect', function() {
  // the connection has been established
});
```

Comment: Note that the events `connect` and `connection` on the server side are now synonyms, so the clause in the answer above that "connection is the server-side equivalent of connect on the client side" is now not entirely valid (at least with v2.1). However, only the `connect` event is valid on the client side. https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#event-connection